# Scrolling gallery script only works sometimes (half the time)

Tags: jquery

This is my first time posting here and I was wondering if you could help me out. I have a scrolling image gallery that only scrolls half the time. you can see it [Here](http://www.brandonbarringerdesign.com) under the "work" section. if it works when you get there just refresh, chances are it won't. The script that runs it is called workScroll.js. I also have other scripts on the page that might be interfering I dont know. Firebug does not get an error. The HTML is contained in the "sc_menu_wrapper" Thank you for any help I can get on this subject.

Comment: +1 so you can have a starting point on your profile ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your script tells itself to scroll only if all images have loaded. The problem is that the script loads faster than the images so most of the time it fails on first load and succeeds if you refresh it. There is already a fix on your code that hangs the code for a while for loading the images but it won't work all the time.

The only working solution for this would be to use jQuery ready() function which tells your script not to do anything unless all elements of the page has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure where I should be applying the ready() function. I have tried to wrap the entire script in document.ready but nothing changed. Again any help would be much appreciated :)